# Twitter Android Client with support for more than two accounts and support for "retweet as"

Tags: android, twitter

I have three twitter accounts. Two of them are closely related and the third is my private twitter accounts. Sometimes, persons I follow with the private account post something, I'd like to retweet by another account.

**Update:** After checking the apps, I miss the threaded view and the number of likes and retweets. So one more criteria below.

I checked following apps:

<kbd>Client

  <kbd>[Talon for Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klinker.android.twitter_l)</kbd>

  <kbd>[Talon for Twitter Classic (open source)](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1067)</kbd>

  <kbd>[TweetCaster](http://tweetcaster.com/)</kbd>

  <kbd>[Twidere](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/664)</kbd> 

  <kbd>[Falcon Pro 3](http://getfalcon.pro/)</kbd>     

  <kbd>[Tweet Lanes](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/663)</kbd> 

  <kbd>[Twitter Client](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/5866)</kbd>

  <kbd>[Twimight](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/665)</kbd>

  <kbd>[Tweetin](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1154)</kbd>

  <kbd>[beeter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.b0ne.android.apps.beeter)</kbd>

  <kbd>[Plume](http://www.myplume.com/)</kbd></kbd>


<kbd>Three accounts

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd></kbd>


<kbd>Retweet as

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd></kbd>


<kbd>280 characters

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd>

  <kbd>yes</kbd></kbd>


<kbd>reply chain

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>outdated app</kbd>

  <kbd>outdated app</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd></kbd>


<kbd>shows number of likes and retweets

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>outdated app</kbd>

  <kbd>outdated app</kbd>

  <kbd>?</kbd>

  <kbd>no</kbd></kbd>

Did I evaluate something wrong? Does someone know alternative apps?

(hint to typeset a table from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231387/218314)

### Reply Chain

By "Reply Chain", I mean the following:

[image: example conversation]

### Number of likes and retweets

Besides the number of likes and retweets, I'd also like to know whether a conversation is going on.

[image: number of likes and retweets]

Comment: [Plume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.touiteur) can deal with multiple accounts and 280 chars. As I only have one account, I cannot test "tweet as". Also consider it contains multiple "trackers" (ads/analytics). See [my list of Twitter apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_twitter) for other possible candidates. Janetter might fit, but you'd need [the pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.janesoft.janetter.android.pro) (Twitter token policy).

Comment: What are "Conversations"? If you're thinking of the "reply chain", the "No" in the Plume line is wrong: tap the latest response, and you'll see the chain of what it responds to. "number of likes and retweets": your own you can find on your profile page (tap your nick) – but what other people liked/retweeted of your tweets I couldn't find in the app either.

Comment: @Izzy I updated the description accordingly. Think, I have to check all Twitter apps in your list and create an [ultimate comparison](https://ultimate-comparisons.github.io/ultimate-comparison-BASE/demo/) out of it.

Comment: What you showed as "reply chain" you can see in Plume when tapping one "participating" message in your timeline (it then shows what that was replying to, back to the initial message, quite similar to your screenshot). So that should be "reply chain: yes" :)